# Window 10 : Appium can't find to the Genymotion emulator within session time

Tags: appium, genymotion

1. Genymotion with VirtualBox download from genymotion site and install properly
2. Add Genymotion pluging on eclipse and set Genymotion directory
3. Add virtual device Nexus9 os version 5.1.0 API 22
4. Add Selenium and Appium java client jar files under project
5. Use Genymotion Android Tool and Custom Android SDK tool as Genymotion ADB tool connection setting
6. Configure Appium Setting and run Appium
7. Run below source code on eclipse

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
   import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
   import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
   import java.net.URL;
   import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
   public class Firstappium {

   static String deviceName = "Nexus9-5.1.0API22";
   static WebDriver driver;
   static String url ="http://127.0.0.1:4720/wd/hub";
   public static void main(String[] args)              {

    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler;
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

   DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
   resultHandler = new     DefaultExecuteResultHandler();


   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Nexus9-5.1.0API22"); 
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("app","G:/appium/apk/cz.hipercalc.apk");
   driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(url),capabilities);
   System.out.println("Appium Driver is launched successfully");
   }
   }
   ```

   8. Every time Appium can't find to the Genymotion emulator within session time. Please check attached screen shot
      [image]